# How to assign a specific point of a plotted function to a specific point of a graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, indexing, axes

I have a series of waves plotted and I was wondering is there any way to create a plot such that the peak of each wave is at the same point so as better to see the difference between each wave.

Each wave is plotted as such with different input variables:

```
plt.plot(x0-X0,peta0)
plt.xlim(936-X0,995-X0)
```

The `plt.xlim` is just to get each wave in the same reference frame.

I have the index of each peak if that helps in this solution.

[image: series of waves]

**Edit:**

The waves plotted above are from quite a complex model and I cannot post the code here. However consider the following example:

```
x = np.linspace(0,500,2000)
eta = np.sin(2*x*np.pi/23) + np.sin(2*x*np.pi/28) + np.sin(2*x*np.pi/33)

peaks = [26,133,193,291,388,474,575,683,831,940,1039,1127,1227,1378,1488,1595,1695,1763,1861,1944]
troughs = [80,190,239,342,430,523,628,748,886,991,1083,1175,1281,1434,1542,1647,1725,1812,1905,1988]
```

Choosing to split at certain troughs of this wave and plotting these sections of the wave like this we get this plot with the peaks marked.

[waves with each peak marked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rl6Xk.png)

```
peak9 = peaks[9] - troughs[8]
peak10 = peaks[10] - troughs[9]
peak11 = peaks[11] - troughs[10]
peak12 = peaks[12] - troughs[11]

plt.plot(eta[troughs[8]:troughs[9]])
plt.plot(peak9,eta[peaks[9]],'xk')
plt.plot(eta[troughs[9]:troughs[10]])
plt.plot(peak10,eta[peaks[10]],'xk')
plt.plot(eta[troughs[10]:troughs[11]])
plt.plot(peak11,eta[peaks[11]],'xk')
plt.plot(eta[troughs[11]:troughs[12]])
plt.plot(peak12,eta[peaks[12]],'xk')
```

The peaks of these plots are at `x = 54, 48, 44, 52` respectively

What I want is to get these peaks to be fixed to the same point (same x and y co-ordinate). i.e. have the black **'x's** all be 'on top' of each other. Is there any way to do this without just rescaling every wave inidividually?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should familiarize yourself with the ["How to ask" page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). That being said, subtracting the x coordinate of the peak from the `x0` variable should probably do the trick, i.e. something like `plt.plot(x0-X0-x0[peak_index],peta0)`.

Comment: Can you provide a sample dataset to reproduce a few curves?

Comment: @mozway I have provided a similar example with sample code. Thanks!

Comment: @JohanC by same point I mean same x and y coordinate. Thanks!

Comment: @Barry "*Is there any way to do this without just rescaling every wave inidividually?*", no there is no matplotlib method to do this directly. You could plot on superimposed axes with each their own scale but it would be more difficult to align them then performing a simple recalling of the curves. It looks like you know how to do this, or do you need help?